# How does the rule "Resources should be closed" check that a connection is closed?

Tags: java, sonarqube

this is a question, not a problem.

I have a class called DSConnectionUtilExternal with one method to retrieve a database connection and one method to close it. This class is in a jar file.

In the other hand I have a project which includes the jar file as a dependency.
In this project I have this code

```
Connection con = null;
ResultSet rsGet = null;
PreparedStatement psGet = null;
try {
    con = DSConnectionUtilExternal.openConnection();

    psGet = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM TEST");
    rsGet = psGet.executeQuery();
    int counter = 0;
    while (rsGet.next()) {
        counter++;
        System.err.println(counter);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (rsGet != null) {
            rsGet.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    rsGet = null;
    try {
        if (psGet != null) {
            psGet.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    psGet = null;
    DSConnectionUtilExternal.closeConnection(con);
}
```

If I delete the content of the method closeConnection at the jar file, sonar doesn't detect that the connection is not closed. I think it's normal, sonar doesn't decompile the jar file to access the jar file code.

So the question is? What is the criterion used by the "Resources should be closed" rule to determine if the connection is closed in the finally clause?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a good reason not to be using try-with-resources?

Comment: The criterion used is whether the reference type implements the (Auto)Closeable interface: you either have to explicitly `close()` it, or use try-with-resources.

Comment: If you care to spellcheck your question, there's a much higher chance that you'll be taken more seriously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct assumption from your question : At the moment SonarJava  (4.11 just released) does not do cross file analysis and have no clue about what's going on in your `closeConnection` method.

However, the rule about unclosed resource has a simple heuristic to avoid false positives to consider resources closed if they are passed to a method named `close`.

SonarJava is on its way to be able to read your jar file and understand the resource is closed there but that is a complicated feature and we hope to deliver it in the near future.

Comment: for sake of history please accept the answer if it is correct.

Comment: Hello @benzonico, could you show jira ticket or something else for tracking this activity, please?

Comment: The impact of a false negative will be too high comparing to a false positive that dev can simply override.